# Can we use Chrome V8 functionalities from GAS?

Tags: google-apps-script, v8, headless-browser

Since Apps Script runs in Chrome V8 engine, would it be possible to use any of V8 functionalities from Apps Script?

I was wondering if it will be possible to build tools like headless browser, webpage screenshot, etc using Apps Script. I haven't read on these though, but would if it would be possible.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

V8 is an ECMAScript engine, which is just one part of a browser. It doesn't know anything about the DOM, or CSS, or rendering, etc. So no, you can't use it to render screenshots of websites.