# How to prevent GOOGLEFINANCE from recalculating?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-finance

I'm using a GOOGLEFINANCE formula, but it keeps updating. I would like it to stay a fixed amount once it has been calculated the first time but I can't seem to figure out a way to do that. I tried Googling for the answer but came up empty-handed. I went to File > Spreadsheet Settings > Calculation, but there doesn't seem to be an option there to prevent recalculations, there only exist options to delay them.

It seems that feature is not built into Google Sheets. But maybe someone who is really good at formulas or a script. Can think of a super smart way to do it with a formula or a script?

Comment: You might wanna try writing a simple script to capture the moving value to another cell as  static value.

just need to use ```getvalue()``` to get the value from the cell with the GOOGLEFINANCE and ```setvalue()``` to put it into the cell desired

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to stop a Google Sheets formula, including those that use GOOGLEFINANCE function to recalculate.

You might replace the formula by it's result. One simple way to do this is by doing copy-paste as value only.

P.S. GOOGLEFINANCE data can't be retrieved by Google Apps Script.

Related

- [Pulling current price change % (Google Finance) with Google Apps Script](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68974452/1595451)